# mac mojave firevault encryption disable error message -69573

Tags: terminal

Hi I have tried to disable a stuck firevault encryption using terminal however, in the terminal it comes up with the error message, "

> Firevault was not disabled (-69573)

I typed in, '`sudo fdesetup disable`' then my username and password after being prompted and that was the message (-69...).

Can someone please assist me to forcequit the firevault please.

My computer is running so slow, I haven't been able to work in days, this might be the reason, I have troubleshooted most things I can think of so I would like to disable the firevault and see how that changes the slowness.

Thanks so much 
Michelle

Comment: it is not recommended to Force quit it.

Comment: Please realize, if you Stop it, it will have to reverse the already decrypted part, which can also take long time.

Comment: you can try this `diskutil cs revert /Volumes/title_drive -passphrase`

You will then be promted with the OS X password unlock/decrypt dialog. After that it starts decrypting.   The title_drive you can look up with `diskutil list or ls -al /Volumes`

Check the status with

`diskutil cs list`